# Use CMake find_package with a custom, bugfixed file

Tags: cmake, cgal, tbb

I have a library (namely CGAL). It provides a FindMODULE.cmake file for a third-party library not shipped with it CGAL (namely Intel TBB). Unfortunately, this file has a bug that I need to fix. (The bug seems to be related to incompatible directory structures, but that's not the point here.)

So the CMakeLists.txt of my project has a line:

```
find_package( TBB )
```

This will invoke FindTBB.cmake which is provided in the directory structure of CGAL.

Now, I need to fix a bug in FindTBB.cmake. I'd like to just copy that file and put the fixed version directly into my project directory.

**How can I tell CMake to use FindTBB.cmake in my project directory (instead of the one provided by CGAL) when calling `find_package`?**

Comment: You can try `set (CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "<your_project_name>_SOURCE_DIR/path/to/fixed/module" ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH})`

Comment: Unrelated, but still: Have you opened an issue for CGAL? They might be interested in fixing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative approach:

1. Copy the file to your module directory and modify it.
2. Call `find_package(TBB)` before you do anything related to CGAL.
3. Use the CMake call used to find / interact with CGAL. If you are lucky, the results of all checks are cached and it work. It still might not work, depending on what is actually done.

Answer (score 0):

The find_package function might be too heavy in this case, you can try just including your relocated .cmake file like this.

```
include(<local path>/FindTBB.cmake)
```